# Converting an layout and app into extra large layouts for android 2.2 application

Tags: android

Hi I am looking at converting my app design to fragments so it can be displayed on the extra large screens.

[image: Layout for small screen devices]

Above is the layout and activity for main screen for small screen devices.

Below is the layout for large screen devices which I have converted.

All of them in layout are `ImageButton` and clicking on each `ImageButton` opens up an activity. All is working well for small screen layout but for big screen layout whenever an `ImageButton` is clicked on left side an activity should be loaded on the right side.

How could I load on clicking an ImageButton on left side of the screen should load its particular activity in right side of the screen. Some gave as fragments but could not make it work. As most fragments uses List on leftside and loads activities on rightside, but what I looking at is ImageeButtons on the left side and its corresponding activities on right side.

Tried running a simple fragments project with the inclusion of `android-support-v4.jar` in build path of the project but not working.Any help would be appreciated.

Pointers to example would be helpful.

thanks.

[image: layout for large screen devices]